# Is It Possible To Include DWG Trueview In The Android SDK As A Tool To Open And View a DWG File?

Tags: android, image, sdk, file-format, dwg

We are developing an application which is able to open and modify a DWG file without converting it to other formats (e.g. PDF, JPG). In this application we need to allow the user to open and view DWG files.

Can someone please help us with this? Or suggest some other ways by which we can open and view DWG files *without converting it to any other image file format*?

Answer (score 1):

> We are developing an application...to
>   open and modify a DWG file

What in particular do you need help with? You're going to be writing an entire application devoted to opening a specific format of a vector drawing file -- this is *no small task*.

DWG seems to be an open standard, you can find the specification [here (PDF link)](http://opendesign.com/files/guestdownloads/OpenDesign_Specification_for_.dwg_files.pdf). To give you an idea of the complexity, it's a 225 page PDF document. That said, you may be able to find an open source DWG Java library that you can modify to use with Android. A cursory Google search brought up [jdwglib (Java DWG Library)](http://jdwglib.sourceforge.net/).