# dwg files:use of jdwglib

Tags: android, eclipse, dwg

i want to write an application for opening and displaying a dwg image on android using eclipse..for that i included the jdwglib jar in the the project.
in this context,is reading a dwg file and diplaying a dwg file the same??
also plz tell me wat should be done after including this library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> in this context,is reading a dwg file and diplaying a dwg file the same??

No, no more than reading a text file and displaying a text file are the same.

> also plz tell me wat should be done after including this library.

You will need to port it to run on Android -- it may or may not work without modification. Then, you will need to write your own DWG drawing routines. This may take you a very long time, since the DWG specification is 225 pages long.

See also: [Is It Possible To Include DWG Trueview In The Android SDK As A Tool To Open And View a DWG File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689785/is-it-possible-to-include-dwg-trueview-in-the-android-sdk-as-a-tool-to-open-and-v)